# Understanding blocks in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used scaffolding to create a CRUD system for posts.  In the controller, I see this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

- What is `respond_to` and where does it come from?  Since it is using the `do` operator, it is some sort of iterable list, I'm assuming. On each `format` in that list, it will perform the `html` and `json` methods.
- How does `{ render json: @posts }` work in relation to the `json` method? Is `render json: @posts` being passed as an argument to the method?  Is `render` and `json` each an object?  I've never seen the colon notation used outside of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **PostsController** inherits methods from **ApplicationController** and **ApplicationController** inherits from **ActionController::Base**. That's where `responds_to` comes from. The subject there worth looking into is "method lookup".
2. `do ... end` is one way of writing a block.
   `{ render json: @posts }` is another way.
3. `json: "foo"` is a more modern alternative to writing `:json => "foo"`
4. `format` is an arbitrary variable you're cooking up to use inside the block. `render` is a method and `:json` is a symbol. `respond_to` will respond to user requests that Rails format responses accordingly.
5. And for understanding the method, there's also this:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

And if you want to look at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L36-L50) (it's a little thick), for example at the `respond_with` method that Paul mentioned, that's in the Rails source here:

**rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb**

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  It seems like there are just many ways of achieving the same thing in Ruby syntax-wise and I'm just not used to reading each way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `respond_to` isn't modern stuff in Rails. But I will provide [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) to explanation anyway.

More modern helper is [respond_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with).

Probably, this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the video, I'll give it a watch.  So do you think the blog tutorial on the main website is outdated then?  Should I bother to continue with it?

Comment: These guides aren't outdated. `respond_to` still works and I didn't hear anything about deprecation in that respect. But with `respond_with` your code will be more concise. I can use whatever you want.